# Is it possible to hide two divs from two different .php pages with a unique Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, templates, dom-events

I have a button in my index.php that shows a menu and hides the content of the page. However it's suppose to work for two different templates. My function basically looks like this :

```
function show_menu();
{
document.getElementById('menu').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('content1').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('content2').style.display="none";
}
```

If I only put one of the content, hide it works. However if I put both contents it doesn't. What's going on? Is that impossible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What error do you get when it does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your issue correctly, but if I do, the problem is, that you cannot set the style of elements that do not exist on your page. You have to check for `null` values:

```
function show_menu()
{
document.getElementById('menu').style.display="block";

var content1 = document.getElementById('content1'),
    content2 = document.getElementById('content2');

if (content1) {
    content1.style.display="none";
}
if (content2) {
    content2.style.display="none";
}
}
```

Comment: **+1** For disappearing semicolon!

Comment: @user1498653, don't forget to Accept this Answer since it's now working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
function show_menu() //Removed the semicolon, could be the culprit causing the problem
{
  document.getElementById('menu').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('content1').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('content2').style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that there is no element with `content1` id in one of your templates. Then your code will fail when accessing the `style` property of a not existing element, halting your script execution and not hiding the `content2`.

Three possible solutions come to my mind:

- Use the same ids in all templates. If both contain a `content` with the same functional purpose, you should name them the same. Your script will work then with all these templates.
- Use different scripts or a variable indicating which template is used so the script can determine the correct ids.
- Check for the element's existence dynamically (you always should do):

```
function show_menu() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu'),
        content1 = document.getElementById('content1'),
        content2 = document.getElementById('content2');

    if (menu)
        menu.style.display="block";
    if (content1)
        content1.style.display="none";
    if (content2)
        content2.style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: **+1** for being late to the party (and with 4 solutions).

Comment: Hey, I'm just late because I brought 3 solutions! :-)

Comment: I'm curious why aren't there not `{ }` after each if statement?

Comment: Actually you have **4 solutions** as you removed that nasty semicolon.

Comment: They aren't needed, there would be only one statement inside. Properly indented, it's shorter and clearer.

Comment: Humm, I ask becasue JSLint (at jsFiddle) would throw errors for each `if statement`. Is that a false positive error then?

Comment: Really? I'm sure you can disable those *warnings*.

Comment: Ahh, warnings it is. I tried looking for the definitive lesson on that but could not find it. Thank you.